# Check in which intervals values of a vector occur and summarize result in R

Tags: r, intervals

Im using the `hdr` and `hdr.den` functions from the `hdrcde` package to calculate a KDE and the peaks of the KDE:

```
require(hdrcde)
df<-faithful


hdregions<-hdr(den=density(df$eruptions,bw=bw.SJ(df$eruptions,method="dpi")*0.5),all.modes=T)


hdr.den(den=density(df$eruptions,bw=bw.SJ(df$eruptions,method="dpi")*0.5))
```

[image: The red lines mark the peaks. The bars represent the probability blue=99%, red=95%, green=50%]

getting the following result:

```
hdregions
$hdr
        [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]    [,6]
99% 1.549814 2.716431 2.743981 2.966948 3.226652 5.15715
95% 1.617094 2.487255 3.353519 5.046328       NA      NA
50% 1.756702 2.009904 4.058298 4.675423       NA      NA

$mode
[1] 1.860365 2.869094 4.143690 4.503392

$falpha
        1%         5%        50% 
0.03428318 0.09972730 0.48195456
```

The `hdregions$mode` in this case represents the peaks and every pair of `hdregions$hdr` represents a "High Density Region" (hdr) interval.

So the intervals for:

```
99% are :  (1.549814 2.716431) (2.743981 2.966948) (3.226652 5.15715)

for 95%: (1.617094 2.487255) (3.353519 5.046328)

and so on.
```

So **what I need** is more or less the `hdregions$hdr` the other way round I would like a list (or data.frame), showing the corresponding modes within the probability (99%,95%,50%) looking something like this:

```
99% 1.860365 2.869094 4.143690 4.503392
95% 1.860365 4.143690 4.503392
50% 1.860365 4.143690 4.503392
```

What I tried so far:

```
interval<-NULL
for (i in row.names(hdregions$hdr)) {
  interval <- rbind(interval, data.frame(LowLimit = hdregions$hdr[i,][seq(1,to=length(hdregions$hdr[i,][!is.na(hdregions$hdr[i,])]),by=2)], UpLimit = hdregions$hdr[i,][seq(2,to=length(hdregions$hdr[i,][!is.na(hdregions$hdr[i,])]),by=2)], ID=i))
}


for (i in hdregions$mode){

  interval[,as.character(i)]<-cbind( interval[,1] <= i & interval[,2] >= i)

}
```

How the "result" looks like:

```
  LowLimit  UpLimit  ID 1.86036518021136 2.8690942707769 4.14368994335195 4.50339178960013
1 1.553237 2.689358 99%             TRUE           FALSE            FALSE            FALSE
2 2.767980 2.956136 99%            FALSE            TRUE            FALSE            FALSE
3 3.231168 5.152859 99%            FALSE           FALSE             TRUE             TRUE
4 1.617957 2.485883 95%             TRUE           FALSE            FALSE            FALSE
5 3.357559 5.044552 95%            FALSE           FALSE             TRUE             TRUE
6 1.754505 2.014823 50%             TRUE           FALSE            FALSE            FALSE
7 4.049855 4.682700 50%            FALSE           FALSE             TRUE             TRUE
```

Well I would appreciate any help with either helping me getting the desired result continuing the way I started, or any other (I guess probably shorter) way leading to the result.